# does linux zero memory released by applications

Tags: linux, memory

I was thinking about making Linux more secure. Can I write code that grabs a bunch of memory and go through them looking for "interesting" stuff?

```
    main()
    {
    char *p = (char *)malloc(10000000);

    scan_for_stuff(p,10000000);
    }
```

I would imagine it'd be hard to find interesting stuff this way, but you never know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Linux does not zero its menory *after* releasing it. Most libraries implement zeroing the memory while allocating it, but this is programming language dependent and can be overridden.

Accessing "warm" memory doesn't seem like a fruitfull attack vector to me. To exploit that, you'll need privileges that can be used in much more effective ways. If you decide to rewrite the malloc function, you need access to replace the glibc library.

Finally, I'd like to mention the [cold boot attack vector](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack). I tried it recently on my own laptop with impressive results. You need physical access (which is not required in your case), but you don't actually have to do anything on the computer; so there is almost no chance of leaving a software audit trail.

Comment: Well, for that kind of an attack, you need to be right there with the computer. Going through warm memory can be done remotely, even through a virus, perhaps. I'm going to see how hard it would be to write my own malloc or sbrk that does not zero the memory. Would it take too long to have the bios zero all physical memory before going into the boot cycle?

Answer (score 4):

Since `malloc` is just a library function, it depends on your implementation of `malloc`. But there's no system call it can use to get access to pages that belong to another process unless that other process did something to give you access to them.

Typical `malloc` implementations get their pages either by using `sbrk` or by mapping `/dev/zero`, both of which give only zeroed pages. If you get non-zeroed pages from a typical `malloc`, it will only be because your process put something in them.

If there was some way for one process to get access to another process's discarded pages, every process would have to zero its pages before discarding them and all kinds of attacks might be possible where you cause a process to crash and then try to get its discarded pages. It makes much more sense just to provide no way for one process to get non-zeroed pages that were last modified by another process unless that first process specifically asked for that behavior.

Comment: I'm not saying you can look at the memory of a live process. Of course that's not possible. I'm asking if linux zeros the memory after the process releases them..It needs to be done at the time of release. Because if you leave it to malloc to do it, the intruder can write his own malloc that doesn't do the zeroing.

Comment: And you should also encrypt or entirely remove swap space. It might be possible to force your computer to start swapping and then scan the swap space for interesting things.

Comment: I guess you could also do the zeroing at whatever system call malloc makes. sbrk itself is a library function so the zeroing can't be done there. It has to be done in the kernel, at the system call that sbrk makes.

Comment: @BingBang You can do it at any time, it doesn't matter when. In fact, you can let hardware do it lazily, if you have a hardware page zeroer. You just have to make sure to draw from the pool of zeroed pages before you give a page to a process. You can do it when you're not busy.